# visual studio convert from lib files to source files

Tags: decompile, visual-studio-2008

I downloaded one of the projects using vc++ and using visual studio 2008. The problem is some of the files are in .lib format, to understand the project completely i want to know the contents of this lib files. Is it possible to extract this .lib files into C files (I am assuming they are written in C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.lib files contain compiled code. Their contents can not be converted back to easily readable and understandable C code.

In the process of compiling C code, a lot of the information that we find useful in understanding the code, such as comments and often also variable names, gets thrown away because that information has no added value to the processor that has to execute the code.

Although it is technically possible to de-compile compiled code, the results are typically not pretty and certainly not easy to understand.

Comment: I have seen something like dumpbin.exe. will it be any help to me?

Comment: @rajesh: No, probably not.